# Localhost tunneling not working in Python code

Tags: python

I am using pagekite.net for tunneling localhost to run my Django app

Now my tunnel url is something like "myapp.pagekite.me".

Now, when I simply run it in browser, its working. But its not working when I simply perform a GET request in python code.

```
import requests
requests.get("http://myapp.pagekite.me")
>>>401
```

Comment: Where is your question related to programming?

Comment: Since Pagekite is a commercial project, they will be happy to give you support.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `401` in your sample refers to an HTTP Response Code:

`401` is `Unauthorized`

- If you sent credentials they are either incorrect, or of insufficient privilege.
- If you didn't send credentials, you are required to authenticate. Have a look for the `WWW-Authenticate` header in the response.